# What's the drawback of Silverlight/XNA cross application?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, xna

XNA is the way to go if you want to make a game on windows phone, but silverlight has some rather large advantages over xna when it comes to pages just containing links and static text.

I'm talking about the main menu, about screen and highscore and game result. Using XAML to create a menu or textbox to hold some text is super easy.

The only screen you got to do in XNA is the game itself. I use static variables (score) to transfer the score to the other screens and that part works great.

So are there any drawbacks by using this kind of project? Or does it not matter at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not really just no good support for it

try this guide: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/iersoy/using-silverlight-in-xna-part-iii-silverlight-menus/

I made it work a while ago.

Answer (score 1):

From memory, Charles Petzold's book, [Programming Windows Phone 7](http://www.charlespetzold.com/phone/), explores this kind of project in an easy to use, tutorial format. It's a free ebook with code samples available from that website.